# Can't created another align child in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am new to dart and am struggling with alignment. In my code, the second align child isn't working. How do I fix this?
Also, is there any other possible way to position widget(like in JavaFX)?
Code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as prefix0;


void main(){
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Budgeting Calculator",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Welcome to a Financial Free Life!"),centerTitle: true),
          body: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
              child: Text(
                "Please enter your state and yearly income",
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
              ),
            ),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              "State",
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
            ),
        ),
          )
        ),
          )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has syntax error and I change to this 
you can wrap with Column and Row 
and use textAlign: TextAlign.left or TextAlign.center

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Welcome to a Financial Free Life!"),centerTitle: true),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Please enter your state and yearly income",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "State",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );

  }
}
```

[image]